Error while installing Ubuntu in E drive (status : 0xc0000225)
status: 0xc0000225 in Windows serverI’m in big trouble right now. I need Help. Recently I was attempting a Ubuntu installation on a Windows Server. The Windows Server have 3 drives C , D , E. After creating a bootable USB drive by rufus I restarted the Windows and its choose bootable media for Ubuntu. While setting Up the ubuntu I choose “Something Else” from the Installation Type and choose “/dev/sda” or “/dev/sda1 which is usb drive may be or may be not ″(Dont remember). allocated two partition swap and Main partition ( Didnt touch nvme which is Windows partition). After the confirmation off “Write changes to disk”. The screen was stuck and can not do nothing. After 6 hours its shows error status : 0xc0000225.
“Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause”
Please help if anyone knows how to solve. I cannot loose the data on the hard drive. :-(

Did you try to install Ubuntu inside a windows ?!

No not inside Windows. I damn sure I choose another disk to install ubuntu

Can you try to start in safe mode ?

What happens if you disconnect the drive you installed Linux on from the server?    Have you tried changing the disk boot order in the BIOS?

Does this answer your question? recover data after repartitioning of disk

Your own screenshot suggests a solution: Boot Windows installation media and proceed to stratup repair. This should repair whatever mess you did when attempting to install Ubuntu. Then, and only then, PLAN for your goal. Do you want a dual-boot? If so there are many tutorials for that but, at first glance, it's nonsensical because any "server" OS tends to be up all the time. There are virtual machines and WSL for the cases where we want to run Linux inside Windows.

For an actual installation you need a serious update as well: swap as a partition isn't needed with Ubuntu that instead uses a swapfile since many years ago. And any modern (i.e. since 2012) system has UEFI, UEFI mode should be used and for said mode an ESP - EFI System Partition -, a small FAT32 formatted partition as well as root. Actually, nowadays this is all you need. Typically when dual-booting we use the same ESP already there and containing the Windows bootloader. Different bootloaders co-exist in the same ESP.

Since your main concern is, "I cannot loose [sic] the data on the hard drive," then the first thing to do is stop using that drive. Do not boot from it. Make a complete drive image or clone, using one of the many free tools, such as dd, Macrium Reflect Free or an alternative. Make your attempts to recover data on the drive image.
From Windows, you can use a third-party tool such as DiskGenius to examine each partition of the mounted drive image or clone for the data you want to recover.

If you have not overwritten that data, it should be easy to copy it to another drive.
If the data was marked as deleted from the file, but not actually erased, it should be possible to recover data with third-party tools such as Recuva or an alternative.
If the data was overwritten, there is a small chance that a commercial data recovery service could get some of it back -- at a cost. Get an estimate in advance.

In the future, on a regular basis, or at least before making major changes, make drive images so that the machine can be restored to the state it was in when the image was made.

Thank you all for your reply. I genuinely appreciate your efforts. I will connect you If I face any issue.

Hey all : I have a question If I create a bootable media in a Pendrive and install the Windows Server in that Pendrive and boot without inserting that Hard Disk. After the installation if I insert the Hard Disk will that erase all the data in that Hard Disk or not. If So, can I recover the data.

You can't install Windows Server in a pendrive. Follow the guide for data recovery, then do a fresh install.
